# have somebody do something

Tags: verbs

[image]

> We don't have any desire to have you **come** into our community,

"Come" in here is present or past participle?

Comment: @LucianSava, I had searched "have sb come", found nothing. Never thought just to search "have sb do sth" ...

Answer (score 1):

It's *past* participle, present participle would be *coming*.

Comment: I wonder it could be particular case of "have somebody do something"

Answer (score 1):

I needed to make another example

we don't have any desire to have you done lots of exercises, just memorise the lesson and you'll be fine.

done: past participle